# Unable to post on to reddit despite having all correct credentials with snoowrap

Tags: node.js, reddit, jreddit, reddit-access-token, redditkit

Receiving an invalid grant error despite all credentials being correct. Does anyone know the routes I should post to and what headers and data I should include?

The code I tried is here:

```
exports.redditPost = async (subreddit) => {
  const redditBot = new snoowrap({
          userAgent: `${process.env.REDDIT_USER_AGENT}`, 
          clientId: `${process.env.REDDIT_CLIENT_ID}`,
          clientSecret: `${process.env.REDDIT_CLIENT_SECRET}`,
          username: `${process.env.REDDIT_USERNAME}`,
          password: `${process.env.REDDIT_PASSWORD}`
      });
  try{
  await redditBot.getSubreddit(subreddit).submitLink({
              title: 'Title of Post',
              url: `https://example.com`,
          })
  } catch(err){
  console.log(err)
  }
}
```

> Error: "Invalid grant" error returned from reddit. (You might have incorrect credentials.)
> at /Users/name/GitHub/project/Main/node_modules/snoowrap/dist/request_handler.js:280:15
> at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:471:21)
> From previous event:
> at snoowrap.updateAccessToken (/Users/name/GitHub/project/Main/node_modules/snoowrap/dist/request_handler.js:275:8)
> at /Users/name/GitHub/project/Main/node_modules/snoowrap/dist/request_handler.js:83:18
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
> at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)

I tried changing my credentials and finding the API routes but can't find the exact ones and what data to include. I want to try and post a link on a subreddit of my choice.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue. Don't use special characters in your reddit password or characters in sequence like 123 or abc. Seems like since it's based off of older reddit, the relics are still intact.